# Updating a component that manages its own state via props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react/redux app. Generally all state changes should be handled via redux but for input's that seems to not work. So I have a component that manages an input, here's it's constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Bind functions now
    this.changeSlider = this.changeSlider.bind(this);
    this.changeFromInput = this.changeFromInput.bind(this);
    this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        min: props.min,
    }
}
```

Once the component has been mounted, it manages it's own state, as such:

```
changeSlider(e) { // input's onClick is binded to this function
    let val = parseInt(e.target.value,10);
    this.setState(_.merge({}, this.state, { min: val })); 
    // update redux state
    _.debounce(this.props.onChange, 50)(val);
}
```

So the component manages it's own state and tell's the rest the app about the changes via the `onChange` prop.

This prop is mounted based on routing:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/Path/1" />    
        <Route path="Path" component={Container}>
            <Route path="1" component={Component} />
            <IndexRedirect to="1" />
        </Route> 
    </Route>
</Router>
```

The `Container` is responsible for grabbing state from the query string:

```
// in Container
componentWillMount() {
    let {min} = this.props.location.query;
    this.props.actions.changeMin(min);
}
```

The `Container` then spreads some props onto it's children, and renders them.

If I visit `/Path/1?min=123123`, the component gets mounted, then the redux dispatch event is fired in componentWillMount(). The props sent to component will be updated, but they will be ignored. They are only used to set the components state in the constructor.

Edit: Selected answer is right. I had tried it before posting this question, but the debounce function was causing some strange behavior.

Comment: It is not really clear what your question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're looking to update the state when the props passed into the component updates.

This is best done in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Bind functions now
    this.changeSlider = this.changeSlider.bind(this);
    this.changeFromInput = this.changeFromInput.bind(this);
    this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        min: props.min,
    }
}

// Add this method
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        min: nextProps.min,
    })
}
```

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: I had tried this and it didn't work, but I found the problem. A coworker had added the `_.debounce` likely to reduce action noise. This was delaying the execution of the message and causing some weird race conditions.